# Hibernate/JPA SQLServer Primary Key Autoincrement

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, auto-increment

I am porting my database from MySQL to SQLServer. I am having problem when during startup the tables are created and i get syntax error. As below

SEVERE: Unsuccessful: create table ANSWER (AID bigint not null auto_increment, ANS varchar(255), NUMBER integer, QID bigint, primary key (AID)) type=InnoDB
Jan 12, 2011 1:25:28 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
SEVERE: **Incorrect syntax near 'auto_increment'.**

I tried to run the above SQL directly in MsSQLServer and got the syntax error regarding auto increment.

The code used to work perfectly fine in MYSql.

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "ANSWER") 
public class Answer implements Identifiable<Long>, Serializable, Comparable<Answer> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "AID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you correctly changed the [SQL dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects) in Hibernate configuration.

Comment: I just logged in to say that i took a break and with fresh mind i found that i had not changed dialect. Spot on axtavt.